# How to make the scp retry till it succeds in case of a failed attempt?

Tags: perl, unix, scp

I have a perl script written in Server B to scp a file periodically for every hour from Server A to Server B.
The problem is sometimes the scp fails for that particular hour because of some issues on the server B.
I want the scp to keep retrying until it succeeds whenever this happens.

The script is:

```
$soc_scp=`scp -r user\@some_ip:\/home\/hbase\/hourly\/$datehr\.tar\.gz \/home\/hbase\/hourly\/$datehr\.tar\.gz`;


$echo_soc=`echo $?`;

if($echo_soc != 0)
{
$soc_scp=`scp -r user\@some_ip\:\/home\/hbase\/hourly\/$datehr\.tar\.gz \/home\/hbase\/hourly\/$datehr\.tar\.gz`;
}
```

I have not specified the ip for security reasons.Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of the backticks, try calling `scp` with `system()`. That captures `scp`'s exit status instead of its output. Then you can check it and retry if it was nonzero.

```
sleep 1 while system "scp -r user\@some_ip:/home/hbase/hourly/$datehr.tar.gz /home/hbase/hourly/$datehr.tar.gz";
```

This will try `scp` forever at 1s intervals until success.
To limit the number of tries to 10:

```
my $tries = 0;
while (system "scp -r user\@some_ip:/home/hbase/hourly/$datehr.tar.gz /home/hbase/hourly/$datehr.tar.gz") {
    last if $tries++ > 10;
    sleep 1;
}
```

Comment: $echo_soc=`echo $?` line actually captures the scp's exit status if am right

Comment: Assuming `scp` and `echo` are running in the same shell. But it's not the case.

Comment: `sleep 1` waits one second. I just gave it as an example. The program will repeat attempting `scp` until it succeeds.

Comment: oh, so i can state the time in seconds that the scp will wait to retry again if the command fails for the first time right?will this work if the scp fails the second time too?i mean until the exit status is zero this while loop will keep happening right?

Comment: Yes, this will repeat to attempt `scp` at 1s intervals until it succeeds. If you want to limit the number of retries, you'll need a counter too.

Comment: Thanks for making this clear:) but jus out of curiosity ,when u mean a  counter,is it like maintaing a variable and jus checking if that value reaches hundred or something then break out and stop retrying? if u can an example for this would be very helpful

Comment: I've added an example with a counter.